# Can the CMS editors set up a specific page to require authentication - Sitecore

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

I was wondering if it is possible to make it so the editors within sitecore can set it so you require a username/login to only one specific page.

www.yourwebsite.com  - No password required
www.yourwebsite.com/internalstuff - password required and set within CMS by the editors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained extensively in the [Security Administrator's Cookbook](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/securityadministratorscookbook-usletter.pdf) that is supplied by Sitecore.

This is what you need to do, in a few short steps:

- Create a user group with the `User Manager` (on the `Extranet` domain, that's how it's called by default, could be different in your installation)
- Add users to the group
- Go to the `Security Editor`, select the item(s) you want to protect, and disallow `Read` rights for the Anonymous user (this makes it impossible for not-loggedin users to view it)
- Enable `Read` rights on your item(s) for your new user group

Make sure to read the cookbook so you know how to use security inheritance properly. That will save you a lot of time in the future.

Comment: I'm guessing by user group you mean - Sitecore role? Since I don't see anything about user groups in the documentation. But I can assign users to a role and access rights to that role.

Comment: I mean a Role indeed, sorry :-)

Comment: So using this method, you'd have to explicitly go to www.yourwebsite.com/sitecore  and log in using a user associated with the role you've created, THEN you can get to that area that you've blocked off. Makes sense. Unfortunately our sitecore login is not integrated into AD, and maintaining all staff accounts within it is not practical. .

Comment: Is it possible for it to behave similar to asp.net forms auth? you try to hit that part of the site and it'll ask for authentication, authenticate you then redirect you back?
 I think I have a way to use your method and have it not... too bad.

Comment: Nevermind. If my first comment is true (you need the actual sitecore login page) it won't work. We disable that on the CD server.

Comment: You wil need to code some to allow users to log in on the website. It would involve creating a sublayout containing a login form and some code-behind that logs in the user using the Sitecore API.

Comment: You can code an authentication request through the API? And that would work even with the /sitecore portion disabled? If so - That may be the eventual solution.

Comment: Yes, you can. Take a look at Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login()

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's possible with no coding if you have Web forms for Marketers installed. It's not an enterprise ready login with e-mail activation etc. but it works. First, you should of course set up access rights and roles as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15881477/1007278) by Ruud plus you need WFFM ready with forms styled and a placeholder configured to accept forms.

- Go to WFFM and create a registration form (username as single-line text field, password as password-confirmation field)
- as save action add "Create User" (configure correct domain/role there) (you could also add a "User Login with Password action and log the user in directly after registration)
- add the registration form to a public page
- create a login form (username as single-line text field, password as password field); again map the data to the username, password and domain set up for your extranet)
- add the login form to a public page
- enjoy :)

Note: this requires you to have write access to the asp.net user tables (by default set up in the core database). Make sure your security requirements are compliant with that. And as already mentioned this will not give you a basic e-mail validation up on registration.